# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: opencv

I'm getting the error instead of installing all the dependencies like python3.6, numpy, opencv, open-contrib-python.

I've tried to upgrade opencv.

```
import cv2
from cv2 import *
import numpy as np 
import sqlite3
import os


conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

fname = "recognizer/trainingData.yml"
if not os.path.isfile(fname):
  print("Please train the data first")
  exit(0)

face_cascade = 
 cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read(fname)
```

Error message

> AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Comment: I am facing same problem, pls post the answer here if it is solved?

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. And here is how I solve the problem.

**1)** opencv-contrib and opencv must have the exactly same version.

**2)** I  have 4.1.2.30 version for both opencv and I still get the error. After that I changed the version of them. I am using 3.4.8.29 version for the both opencv. Thats solve my problem.

I hope it will work!